# What is the purpose of /proc/config.gz

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

Please what is the purpose of the `/proc/config.gz` file in my Linux server filesystem?

Is it some backup file, or it is an updated file by the Linux system? Can I change it?

Answer (score 8):

This enables you to get the kernel configuration, with which your kernel was compiled.

Usually you use it, if you want to build a new kernel, but you don't have the actual configuration of your running kernel. See [Linux Kernel Configuration](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/ch08.html)

Why you want to change it? Normally you can't, it should be read only from userspace view.

---

By the way, all files under `/proc` comes from the `procfs` which provides informations from the kernel to the userspace and backwards. The newer approach is the `sysfs` usually mounted under `/sys`, which provides a convenient way to communicate with the kernel from userspace.

Comment: It can also be useful to determine if your kernel was actually compiled with support for something. If you know you need a specific feature, you can look in /proc/config.gz to determine its status in your kernel.